# Stop transitions - masonry & jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have a tiles structure design as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

So I am facing two problems using masonry.

1- When I call masonry on page load two things happen,

a) some of my tiles have dynamic data so their height varies time to time(expand like ISO above. That is normal I need this functionality.

b) But second thing is transitions, i.e. the tiles along with Iso shifts as the height increases, which gives transition affect to my page, How to stop that transitions.

2- Few events are there in my page where tile  expands and then collapse in that situation also transition affect appear i.e. user can see moving tiles on page at that point of time.

I want to make my site transition free! Is there any solution available for this?

Comment: Can you maybe show us some code or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: Give [jQuery.fx.off](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.off/) a try.